# Swift error handling with multiple catch and conditions based on the error's enum associated value

Tags: swift, error-handling, enums

Is there a way to catch errors with some condition on the catch based on the value of the associated value of the error enum?

Example:

```
enum Errors : Error {
    case error1(str: String?) // optional associated value
    case error2
    case error3
}

func f() throws {
    throw Errors.error1(str: nil)
}


do {
    try f()
}
catch Errors.error1(let str) {
    if(str != nil) {
        print(str!)
    }
    else {
        //throw the same error to be caught in the last catch
    }
}
catch {
    print("all other errors")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes of course!

In a `catch`, you can do pattern matching with the error, just like in a switch statement. You can read more about this in the [Swift guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html#ID512) under the section "Handling errors using Do-Catch". This means you can use `where`:

```
do {
    try f()
}
catch Errors.error1(let str) where str != nil{

}
catch {
    print("all other errors")
}
```