# Swift Pattern Matching in Catch for Enum with Associated Values

Tags: swift, pattern-matching, try-catch

I would like to figure out how to pattern match against an enum-with-associated-value property of an error type in a `catch`. Everything works as expected with an enum *without* associated values, but I can't seem to figure out the correct pattern for this situation.

```swift
struct MyError: Error {
    enum Size {
        case big, small
    }

    enum Solution {
        case runAway
        case other(String)
    }

    let size: Size
    let solution: Solution
}

func action() {
    do {
        // ...
    }
    catch let error as MyError where error.size == .big {
        // This works fine, as `size` has no associated values.
    }
    catch let error as MyError where error.solution == .other {
        // I want to handle all cases of `Solution.other` here, regardless of the associated value.
    }
    catch {
       // ...
    } 
}
```

The second `catch` pattern won't compile (as expected due to the enum with associated value). The usual way I'd accomplish this would be a `if case .runAway = error.solution {...}`, but integrating this in the `catch` pattern is the problem.

I tried many combinations of `if case/let case/case let`, but couldn't get this working in a single `catch` pattern matching statement. This feels like it should be possible given the power and flexibility of pattern matching, so I'm hoping I've just overlooked something.

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56113330/9682885) answer. I think is exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels possible, but isn't :/. What you are trying to use is an enum case pattern. According to [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#grammar_enum-case-pattern), an enum case pattern is only allowed in `switch`, `if`, `while`, `guard`, and `for` statements.

You can add an `isOther` property in `Solution`:

```
var isOther: Bool {
    if case .other = self {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

And then use it in the catch:

```
do {
    // ...
}
catch let error as MyError where error.size == .big {
    // ...
}
catch let error as MyError where error.solution.isOther {
    // ...
}
catch {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the doc reference! The confirmation that this isn't supported in `catch` statements is exactly what I was hoping to find.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things which should be fixed in your sample:

1. To compare cases of an enum it should be equitable, isn't it? For such a simple enum just mark `Solution` as `Equitable`.
2. Default case for a catch isn't handled, so you need to add it, eg:

   `do {
       ...
   }
   catch let error as MyError where error.size == .big {
       // This works fine, as`size`has no associated values.
   }
   catch let error as MyError where error.solution == .runAway {
       // I want to accomplish this comparison.
   }
   catch let error {
       ...
   }`

Comment: Thanks. Conforming to `Equatable` does allow `.runAway` to be matched, but still does not allow comparison with the `.other` case containing the associated value.

Comment: Yep, that's expected behaviour, you can still compare cases with associated values eg: `error.solution == .other("some string")`, because marking the enum as equitable generated default comparison function. If you would like to compare only cases without associated values just implement a custom comparison function

Comment: `static func == (lhs: Solution, rhs: Solution) -> Bool {
            switch (lhs, rhs) {
            case (.runAway, .runAway):
                return true
                
            case (.other, .other):
                return true
                
            default:
                return false
            }
        }`
and add `catch let error as MyError where error.solution == .other("")` then